# Using params in nodejs(expressjs)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to set params for routing in my webapp by string:

```
app.param('id', /^\d+$/);
```

I need it to do for better routing setting, like

```
app.get('/post/:id', show);
```

But I'm getting next error:

```
throw new error ('invalid param() call for ' + name + ', got ' + fn)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you format your question and make it less allusive ? It's hard to get what happens for you.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Have you read the documentation? http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.param

Comment: @SomeGuy I read documentation, and i'm writing my routing just like it written in example id docs. 
But i'm getting error, when trying add

    app.param('id', /^\d+$/);

Comment: @Foker What version of express are you using ? What's the stack trace of your error ?

Comment: @dystroy version - 3.5.0
error coming from node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js, if you talking about that

Answer (score 4):

From your comments, it seems evident that you forgot to include the part of the example code which allows support for Regular Expressions in `app.param`. [The documentation](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.param) has the following code before `app.param('id', /^\d+$/);`:

```
app.param(function(name, fn){
  if (fn instanceof RegExp) {
    return function(req, res, next, val){
      var captures;
      if (captures = fn.exec(String(val))) {
        req.params[name] = captures;
        next();
      } else {
        next('route');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Include that, and you should be fine.

Alternatively, you could just use the [`express-params`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-params) module, that includes that code for you.